# webpack externals giving error "ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, external

I have a settings file, which is modified *after* the webpack build. So, I am trying to load this as an external resource at runtime. The file (`settings.json`) resides in the root of the website.

I've added the file in `webpack.config.js` under externals

```
var config = {
    entry: {
        main: './scripts/main.js'
    }
};

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    config.externals = {
        settings: "require('./settings.json')"
    };

    return config;
}
```

then I attempt to export it using a module `settings-service.js`

```
import settings from 'settings';

export default settings;
```

However, I am receiving the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Which is coming from the line (from the transpiled js)

```
/***/ "settings": /*!*********************************************!*\  
!*** external "require('./settings.json')" ***!   
\*********************************************/ 
/*! no static exports found */ /***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = require('./settings.json');

/***/ })

/******/ });
```

It looks like webpack is correctly not bundling the `settings.json` file. But I don't understand why the transpiled js is not valid.